# Minimize, maximize and close buttons are gone on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, minimize, maximized

Something caused the minimize, maximize and close buttons to disappear for maximized windows on Ubuntu 18.04. Only some GNOME setting windows show them correctly when maximized. Minimize, maximize buttons are enabled. I can't find any settings differences between this system and another one, which shows buttons correctly. Any clues?

**EDIT**

Files and Text Editor have the buttons when maximized:

[image]

[image]

Terminal and Nomacs don't have the buttons when maximized:

[image]

[image]

**SOLUTION**

It was the GTK Title Bar being enabled, which I couldn't see because Gnome Extensions for Chrome was giving me `Application is not available` errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since gtk3 is controlling the buttons in the "CSD" header (as opposed to the Window decorations a Window manager used to control) it looks like your theme has changed that behviour. If you select another theme, they might appear again. Basically that's fixable by changing the gtk.css of your theme (look for the **headerbar, .maximized** selector).
The default theme Ubuntu ships with should show the button decorations. Make sure that no gnome shell plugin like [this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1267/no-title-bar/) is installed

Comment: It seems that it is a problem with title bar. As a newbie, I was trying to use Gnome extensions plugin for Chrome, but it was shaky and stopped working. Now it works again and indeed it was the GTK Title Bar.